# Are stacked NN the second generation of NN?

Tags: neural-network, terminology

[Spiking Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiking_neural_network) are said to be the NN's third generation. Feed-Forward NN are the first. What is the second Generation? Stacked NN?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Kumar, Satish. [Neural networks: a classroom approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=y67YnH4kEMsC&pg=PA578&lpg=PA578&dq=%22second+generation+of+neural+network+models%22&source=bl&ots=_frZdlnbTp&sig=UV1yMvV9eVt5iOGp_U-1yB7jdXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizz-HiusHPAhXk44MKHSvoB38Q6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q&f=false). Tata McGraw-Hill Education, 2004.:

> The first generation of neural network models employed McCulloch-Pitts TLN type neuron. They were essentially switching networks. The second generation of neural network models employed a smooth sigmoids. The sigmoidal function was motivated by the increase in firing rate of a neuron with the net input, which is saturates at a certain maximum frequency. The third generation of neural network models will use spiking neurons which encode information in spike trains.

Comment: Interesting: The spiking neurons are continious like the sigmoids and have threshold like the McCulloch neurons. Just something to take note of.

Comment: So the generations are not about the networks, but only the neurons themselves?